# Page background and body background not displaying as I thought they would

Tags: html, css, styling

I am working on this site: http://www.problemio.com and I am trying to get the entire background and the body background set.

I am trying to get the areas on the very left and right sides to be the blue color, and the background of the body to be the gray color.

Instead, what is happening is for some reason, everything is blue except the header is all gray lol.

My css file is here http://www.problemio.com/main.css

How can I get the colors working as I intended? Also, I don't mind keeping the top area with the gray background as I think now it looks relatively ok.

Comment: are you want the grey color come behind the content area & the blue comes rest the screen ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@genadinik;

first problem is that your `container` div didn't take entire `height` of the child divs so how have to it [clear](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html) 
. Second: right now it's takes entire `width` of the screen so you have to define width to it

```
 .container{
  overflow:hidden;
  width:1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The default color on your page is blue:

```
body {
    background-color : #4dbefa;
}
```

It looks like you have a div with the id `bd` that contains your main content. Since you haven't specified the background color for this div, it's effectively transparent and you'll see whatever background that's behind it. You'll need to override the background color on this div if you want the color to be different.

```
div#bd {
        background-color: #ccc; /* some form of gray */
}
```

Comment: just added the style you suggested to the bd div, but it somehow didn't make a difference in how the page looks

Comment: I wonder if your `bd` div isn't taking up any vertical space. Trying giving your `bd` div a border, preferably a bright color like red, to see how much of the page it's actually occupying. Fix markup errors could also help here, since I noticed quite a few when **[validating](http://validator.w3.org/)** your page.

Comment: Yeah that bd div didnt take much space. Not sure what it is for. I should probably just get rid of it, huh?